# What is the default installlevel for windows installer?

Tags: windows-installer

If you do not provide any installlevel argument to msiexec, what is the default value that the Windows Installer Framework assumes?  My tests seem to indicate 1, but I can't find any documentation that corroborates this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If no value is specified, the install level defaults to 1.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369536(VS.85).aspx